# Script to extract the last word in the last line of a text file

Tags: windows, batch, script

I am trying to extract the last word of a findstr results query

The command I run

```
findstr /i %1 x:\itlogs\who_when.txt | findstr /i %2
```

the results I get

```
12/02/2018 10:17:58     SmithS         Steve Smith                     B0K9VY1
13/02/2018 09:29:13     SmithS         Steve Smith                     B0K9VY1
```

What I need from the results is that last word ***B0K9VY1*** so i can run `SCCM RemoteControl $computername`

(it will *always* be the last word on the last line of the results from my `findstr` query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What I need from the results is that last word B0K9VY1

Try the following batch file and tweak to taste:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=6" %%i in ('findstr /i %1 x:\itlogs\who_when.txt ^| findstr /i %2') do (
  set last_word=%%i
  SCCM RemoteControl !last_word!
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### But I only want the last word of the last line, not every line!

Move `echo !last_word!` outside of the for loop as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=6" %%i in ('findstr /i %1 x:\itlogs\who_when.txt ^| findstr /i %2') do (
  set last_word=%%i
  )
SCCM RemoteControl !last_word!
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: Worked well thanks.   How do i filter it to only the very last entry?   Currently it is listing every line (but only the machine name now which is great)

Comment: @ChrisPage So you only want the last word on the last line? Move `echo !last_word!` outside of the for loop. And replace the `echo` with `SCCM RemoteControl`